# reStructuredText class directive mistranslated by sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have the following markup:

```
.. class:: something

This
```

Based on the [documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#class), I'd expect something like

```html
<p class="something">This</p>
```

as the output from `sphinx-build`.  Instead of this, I get the following:

```html
<dl class="class">
  <dt id="something">
    <em class="property">class </em>
    <tt class="descname">something</tt>
    <a class="headerlink" href="#something" title="Permalink to this definition">¶</a>
  </dt>
  <dd></dd>
</dl>

<p>This</p>
```

Any idea about what I am missing?

The `sphinx-build` version is 1.2.2.